# How to write a request funds function in solidity

Tags: solidity, hardhat, smart-contract-wallets, function

Hello everyone…I am trying to build a dapp where a user can request funds or ethers from a specific address and then that address can approve that function, then the person who requested the fund will get it when it has been approved…how can I go about this in Solidity  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with only Solidity.
You'd have to create a contract that records requests for a specific address.
maybe something like:

```
struct Requests {
  uint256[] amountOfRequest;
  address[] demander;
}

mapping(address => Requests) requestsPerAddress;

function issueRequest( address _from, uint _amountRequested) external {}

function acceptRequest(uint _requestIndex) external {}
```

After that a solution could be to track the transactions for specific function calls or events.
Openzeppelin Defender can do that for you with the Sentinel

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/sentinel

and trigger a code snippet with Autotask

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/autotasks